# Is it possible to define to bean with same name in two different namespace without using @Qualifer and @resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean, spring-ioc

I have two packages and beans as below in spring

com.myapp.test1

- myService

com.myapp.test2

- myService

part 1:The solution for this situation is giving name for beans like this:

```
@Service(name="myService1")
myService
```

and

```
 @Service(name="myService2")
 myService
```

and Inject like

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("myService1")
```

Is there any solution without part1 approach, I required define two bean with same name in different namespace without `name & @Qualifier`

for theme (I am using spring).

Comment: So your beans are two instances of the same class? Or different classes being in 2 separate classes?

Comment: @Matt there are two different bean in different namespace with same name

Comment: By namespace, you mean package right? And a bean is not in a package it is an instance (or several if not singleton) of a class.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring will give a name to the bean based on [AnnotationBeanNameGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html). So for same class name (even though on different packages), they will be givem the same name and fail.

As you tried the simplest solution is to give a name to one (or both) of the beans in your `@Service` annotation.

But then, you won't have to specify this name when injecting it as injection is looking for class instance, and in this case both classes are different.

`com.myapp.test1.MyService` is a different class than `com.myapp.test2.MyService`

And if both are annotated with `@Service` and managed by Spring, you can inject them as follow :

MyService 1 :

```
package com.myapp.test1;

@Service
public class MyService {

}
```

MyService 2 :

```
package com.myapp.test2;

@Service("myService2")
public class MyService {

}
```

Injecting them :

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    //no need for qualifier here
    private com.myapp.test1.MyService myService1;
    @Autowired
    //no need for qualifier here
    private com.myapp.test2.MyService myService2;
    ...
}
```

That said, it would be easier to give different names to both classes.

Comment: it has run time error Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'MyService ' for bean class [a2.asena.service.test.MyService ] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize this didn't work. I guess by default Spring gives a name based on the class name only and will fail if both class names are the same. You just need to define a different name for your @ Service annotation though and not necessaraly in your @ Autowired

Comment: thanks for your solution. but I have mentioned it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Another solution would be not to use Spring's ComponentScan and declare your bean in your config with `@Bean`. This will result with bean being named as the method in the config.